# What is the recommended way to perform multiple mutations in sequence in RTK Query?

Tags: rtk-query

Which way is recommended to perform multiple mutations in sequence using RTK Query?

```
  const [
    updateProfile, 
  ] = useUpdateProfileMutation();

  const [
    updatePost,
  ] = useUpdatePostMutation();


  const performMutipleMuations = async () => {
    const data= await updateProfile(newData);
    await updatePost(data);
  };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ultimately using `unwrap` made the trick.

```
  const performMutipleMuations = async () => {
    const data= await updateProfile(newData).unwrap();
    await updatePost(data).unwrap();
  }
```

Comment: ***Don't*** forget to wrap the asynchronous logic in a `try/catch` to handle Promise rejections.